# C++, WinAPI, ShellExecute, system difference

Tags: c++, winapi

What is the difference between `system()`, `ShellExecute()` and `CreateProcess()`?
I want to call the uninstaller of application (exe and msi).

Comment: All three of them are documented, and are easily found using any web search engine. Did you try doing those searches before asking here?

Comment: `system()` just calls `CreateProcess()` to run `cmd.exe /k <command>`

Answer (score 1):

Uninstallers likely require the right permissions, so that means you need `ShellExecute`. The other two do not support UAC.

Comment: How can i use shellexec for msi and simple exe uninstallers?

Comment: Pass runas for the verb to run as admin. Don't ever use `ShellExecute` because it doesn't report errors propertly. Use `ShellExecuteEx`. For more details, read the documentation.

Comment: "*Uninstallers likely require the right permissions*" - and as such, should be manifested accordingly, thus you shouldn't need to use `runas`. Just run the EXE normally and let the OS elevate as needed.